# Probability that the fox will survive the hunt

Tags: probability

**Problem**

A hunter sees a fox $40$ meters away and shoots at him. If the fox survives the shot, he runs away $10$ m/s and the hunter continues to shoot every $2$ seconds until she kills him or the fox vanishes.

The probability that the hunter will shoot the fox is $10000\cdot x^{-3}$ where $x\ge 40$ is the distance between the hunter and the fox. If the fox gets shot, the probability that he will die is $1/5$, independent of how many times he got shot.

What is the probability that the fox will survive?

**My solution**

Let $B$ be the event that the fox dies and $A_i$ be the event that the fox dies at the $i$th shot. Since $A_i$ are mutually exclusive we have $P(B)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P(B|A_i)P(A_i)=10000\cdot 4/5\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}1/(40+20i)^3\approx 0.2$. Therefore the probability that the fox survives is $1-0.2=0.8$.

I'm not really sure about this though. It is suspiciously likely that the fox survives.

Comment: "or the fox vanishes"?  When does the fox vanish?

Comment: The right question is "How old is your math professor?"

Comment: @RobertIsrael over the curve of the Earth? about 7km on a smooth Earth (4.5 for the hunter, 2.5 for the fox). I think the bullets run out of range before this though, and of course the probabilities get vanishingly small too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditional probability of the fox surviving shot #$i$, given that it survives up to that point, is $1 - 10000/(5 (40 + 20 i)^3) = 1 - 1/(4 (2+i)^3)$, $i=0, 1, \ldots$.  Thus the probability of eventual survival is 
$$ \prod_{i=0}^\infty \left(1 - \frac{1}{4 (2 + i)^3}\right) $$
Maple says this is
$$ {\frac {-16}{3\; \Gamma \left( -\sqrt [3]{2}/2 \right) \Gamma
 \left( \left(1-i\sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{2}/4 \right) \Gamma
 \left( \left( 1+i\sqrt {3} \right) \sqrt [3]{2}/4 \right) }} \approx 0.950215097
$$